# How to fetch the next records from a table in sql database one after other

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am developing an application where I need to send the Emails to all the users in the table. Since the number of users is in millions, so to select all the users at once won’t do any good. Is there any way I can send emails in a group of 20 or 30 users so that the next time it will select the next 20 users dynamically and send emails. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "Next" by what order? If you want to define "next" and "previous", you **must** have an explicit ordering (`ORDER BY (somecolumn)`) defined

Comment: I hope you're not creating a spammer program. ;) Do the entries in your users table have any kind of sequence? ID, CreatedAtDate or something?

Comment: Table have customer Id's which are not sequenced. Any help how to achieve this. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "not sequenced"? Is `Id` of type `int` or `bigint`? Or is it a `uniqueidentifier`? As marc_s asked, how do you determin what a "next" record is?

Comment: The customer Id has type Nvarchar for example (AC-3D01GUSC02-221271). It is uniqueidentifier.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or higher you can use Row_Number() to get the desired number of users.

Example:

```
Select * from (Select *, Row_number()over (order by UserEmail) as Row from Userprofile) T
Where T.Row Between 30 and 40
```

How ever if you are using SQL Server 2000 there is nothing like Row_Number().
You will have to use IDENTITY() function and a temporary table.

Example:

```
SELECT IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS RowNumber, UserEmail INTO #temp 
    FROM Userprofile ORDER BY UserEmail ASC
SELECT * FROM #Temp Where #Temp.RowNumber Between 10 and 20 ORDER BY RowNumber DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Make sure to drop the Temporary table.

Comment: If someone adds more rows to the UserProfile table while the emails are being sent then there is a high possibility that someone will get 2 emails.

Comment: @ Peter Henell -i have changed UserName to UserEmail. As this is the userprofile table it is not likely to have 2 users the same email address. So, i don't think someone will get 2 emails because of having same email addresses. But there is another problem. During sending emails new users may be created and as we are using Order By in the query it may be possible that some users will get multiple emails and some will get none. To fix this up we can use a marker in the database to mark which emails are sent successfully and after sending all the emails set the marker to false for all the user.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table *EmailReceivers* that you fill with all the email addresses that you wish to send to.
Then select top 30 from that table, and once you have done sending the email you delete that record from that table. When the table is empty you are done.

```
create table EmailReceivers
(
    Id bigint identity(1, 1) primary key clustered,
    EmailAddress varchar(5000)
)  

-- Now fill this table with all the email addresses
insert EmailReceivers(EmailAddress)
select Email from users....


-- Select top 30 to send
select top 30 Id, EmailAddress from EmailReceivers order by Id

-- When done sending, delete the receiver from the table
delete EmailReceivers where id = @id
```

Doing this many deletes can be bit of a performance hog, so you might want to delete in chunks. Do so by delete all of the rows you previously selected. Just grab the highest ID from that batch and delete all the rows with IDs lower or equal to that ID.

```
delete EmailReceivers where id <= @maxIdFromLastBatch
```